# Why there's no autocomplete, even though hint show possible values with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I have an interface and a class with a constructor that receives a property based on a given generic type:

```js
export enum AccountTypesEnum {
    Accounts= "Accounts",
}

export interface AccountTypes {
    [AccountTypesEnum.Accounts]:  "/foo" | "/bar" | "/baz",
}

class Account<T extends AccountTypesEnum> extends Resource {
    public constructor(endpoint: AccountTypes[T]) {
    // ...ommited
```

When instantiating the `Account` class, I expect the editor to show me the possible `endpoint` values, if I pass `AccountTypesEnum.Accounts` as it's generic type:

```js
new Account<AccountTypesEnum.Accounts>(/* AUTOCOMPLETE_HERE: /foo, /bar or /baz */ )
```

- If I hover over `Account` I see that the possible values for the argument are indeed one of the ones I specified.
- If I type anything different from the three values, IntelliJ will show me TS error
- If I try to use the autocomplete feature, it **WON'T** shows me one of the three possible values.

I haven't tried in other editors than IntelliJ so I'm not sure if this a TypeScript thing or IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by recreating the `.idea` folder. I've closed webstorm, deleted the `.idea` folder and opened webstorm again.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct.

if you see the error than TS language service is working as expected.

tested with in webstorm 2020.1 with TS 3.8.3; try updating your IDE.

Comment: That's the exact same editor and typescript version as me. Still, I only see the suggestions, no autocomplete feature. Might be something with my `tsconfig`.

Comment: just tested with VS code, works as expected... (if i'm not wrong, autocomplete is provided by ts language service, check your `tsconfig`)

Comment: It's something with my webstorm. The suggestion works correctly with VSCode and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in Webstorm 2020.1:

[image]

If the issue persists on caches invalidation (**File > Invalidate caches, Invaalidate and restart**), please submit a ticket to Jetbrains support

Comment: I will do, tried your suggestion, plus some other ones, no success.